# Multiple Invocation name -Google Assistant Dialog flow integration

Tags: bots, dialogflow-es, google-assist-api

While setting up google assistant from dialog flow, It allows to have one invocation name to be used to invoke my agent. Is there any possibility that I can have multiple invocation name to trigger my agent. For eg, "Talk to my app" , "Talk to special app" and "Talk to my own app"

Answer (score 0):

At overview page of **Actions on Google**, go to **"get ready for deployment"** section and select **"Enter information required for listing your Action in the Actions directory"** there in **"sample invocations"** part you can add multiple invokation examples, see if it helps!

[image]

Comment: When you create an app name as "my app", it has to stick to the app name, "ask my app about weather" or "talk to my app to get weather". When you include "ask  special app to get the weather" it didn't work. somewhere in the text it needs to match "my app". This space is only a suggestion to the user not the multiple invocation name.

Comment: No, you can't give alternate invocation names here. This will result in an error. Your sample utterances MUST contain the invocation name that you've defined in your project set-up.